# Iphone XCode My Countdown no longer Animates

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, countdown

Hey Guys another question!

Once again I would like to state that i am new to this and therefore my ability to understand the language Objective C and the Xcode application is limited! So Your help really and truly is appreciated greatly!

I built a countdown app that shows when a radio station is going to be going live, the countdown worked perfectly and updated in realtime once a second, then I inserted it into an "If-Statement" so that when the day of the station launch arrives the countdown disappears, but now my countdown does not update in realtime it just sits static.

The following is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        self.today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

        NSString *launchDay = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"11/26/2010 11:59:59"];
        NSDate *currentDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:launchDay];

        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:currentDate options:0];


        if ([today timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate] <= 0 ){   
                    self.today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
        countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second ];
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [self updateLabel]; 
        days.text = @"Days";
        hours.text = @"Hours";
        mins.text = @"Mins";
        secs.text = @"Secs";
        until.text = @"Until XtremeFM Launch!";
    }

    else {
        countdownLabel.text =@"XtremeFM is LIVE";

    }
}
```

Guys any help is greatly appreciated and I really hope someone out there can help me!

Thanks guys,
Phil

ok here is the code for the whole .M file of the home screen

```
#import "XtremeFMViewController.h"

@implementation XtremeFMViewController



/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/



@synthesize countdownLabel, today, timer, todayDate, days, hours, mins, secs, until;


-(void)updateLabel {
    self.today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

    //NSString *launchDay = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"11/26/2010 11:59:59"];
    //NSDate *currentDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:launchDay];

    //NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    //int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    //NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:currentDate options:0];


}

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        self.today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

        NSString *fathersDay = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"11/26/2010 11:59:59"];
        NSDate *currentDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:fathersDay];

        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:currentDate options:0];


        if ([today timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate] <= 0 ){   
                    self.today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
        countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second ];
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [self updateLabel]; 
        days.text = @"Days";
        hours.text = @"Hours";
        mins.text = @"Mins";
        secs.text = @"Secs";
        until.text = @"Until XtremeFM Launch!";
    }

    else {
        countdownLabel.text =@"XtremeFM is LIVE";

    }
}


- (IBAction)watchLive { 

    self.today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *launchDay = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"11/26/2010 11:59:00"];
    NSDate *currentDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:launchDay];

    //NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    //int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    //NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:currentDate options:0];
    //countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second ];



    if ([today timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate] >= 0 ){

        NSString *webpage = @"http://xphiltestpagex.is.livestream-api.com/livestreamiphone/philtestpage/playlist.m3u8";
        NSURL *nswebpage = [NSURL URLWithString:webpage];
        NSURLRequest *nsurl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nswebpage];
        [webView loadRequest:nsurl];

    }
    else {

        UIAlertView*alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Coming Soon" message:@"Feed goes live Friday 26th November 12:00pm" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }


}

-(IBAction)requestsPage {
    RequestsPageViewController *move = [[RequestsPageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    move.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:move animated:YES];
    [move release];
}

-(IBAction)twitterButton {
    RequestsPageViewController *move = [[RequestsPageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    move.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:move animated:YES];
    [move release];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

See I had a (BOOL)animated on the `ViewDidAppear` but I am not sure how to add this into the if-statement (Noob)

Comment: include your code for `updateLabel`. You are only setting the label's text once where it seems that you want the label to update every second.

Comment: please fix the formatting. It appears that you have moved the code that set the label's text (that is now commented out) to the `viewDidAppear` which is only called when the entire view is displayed. I think you need to spend some time reading the following http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW19

Answer (score 0):

I find NSLog() invaluable for tracking down things that don't fire conditionals correctly.

Immediately before your `if()`, go:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [today timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate]);
```

And then look and see what you get on the console.

One place I've messed up this sort of thing is to test the values in the wrong order, so what I expect to be negative is positive and vice versa.

Also, you're leaking pretty much everything you allocate in that code. Go back through and `release` everything you `alloc` please!

Comment: Added this onto the app and ran it in console but nothing was added to a log of any sort, I've ran NSLogs before so I am aware of how they should appear but this just doesn't show anything

Comment: You know what, I said to use %d, it ought to be %f, because NSTimeInterval is a double. I'm surprised you didn't get a BAD_EXEC there... Try it with a %f and see if it says anything sensible.